# Control NetBeans Programmatically using a NetBeans Module

Tags: java, netbeans, module

*I know I should probably be using Eclipse but whatever...*

Usualy at computer science contests I go to, we are given some sample data sets for the problems, such as "prob01.in, PizzaProblem.text, ect.". I am writing a NetBeans Module to make a project and then fill the project with java files of the input files, in the specified location.

**So, on to my question. Is there any way to "control" NetBeans, and use it to make and open projects and files?**

I did a breif google search and did not find anything useful.

Thanks,
-EpicDavi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.netbeans.org/OpenProjectsProgramaticallyInNetBeansIDE#Tutorial_.7C_Open_Projects_Programatically_in_NetBeans

This page only tells you how to open a project programmatically in a Netbeans module, but it should set you on the right path. Unfortunately, I'm not well versed in NetBeans so I don't have much other insight to offer.

Comment: Thanks! All the info is on the page and I see the libraries I need to do so.

Comment: Yeah, I knew should be possible to do because I did something like this for Eclipse to automatically build, package, upload the jars to some hardware, run JUnit tests on the hardware, and format the results in the JUnit plugin for Eclipse. It was some pretty cool stuff, actually.